# Send file by url telegram-api

Tags: java, telegram-bot

How can I set the name of the file that I send in telegrams by url ?

```
new SendDocument()
                .setChatId(message.getChatId())
                .setDocument("https://www.okbhmao.ru/download.php?file=12021");
```

I want to send this file in telegram chat with the name contract.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
new SendDocument()
                  .setChatId(message.getChatId())
                  .setDocument("contract.pdf", new URL("https://www.okbhmao.ru/download.php?file=12021").openStream());
```

Comment: do mark your own answer as accepted so people know can easily find it :)

Comment: @jwenting. You can accept your own answer tomorrow ;)